# Recycle bin in bash problem

Tags: bash

I need to make a recycle bin code using bash. Here is what I have done so far. My problem is that when I move a file with the same name into the trash folder it just overwrites the previous file. Can you give me any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p "$HOME/Trash"
if [ $1 = -restore ]; then
    while read file; do
    mv $HOME/Trash/$2 /$file
    done < try.txt
else
    if [ $1 = -restoreall ]; then
        mv $HOME/Trash/* /$PWD
    else
        if [ $1 = -empty ]; then
            rm -rfv /$HOME/Trash/*
        else
            mv $PWD/"$1"/$HOME/Trash
            echo -n "$PWD" >> /$HOME/Bash/try
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! @Emil has fixed the code formatting in the question for you. Please take a moment to read the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the Ask a Question area, and [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. (There's also a preview box shown under the Ask a Question box where you can preview your question.)

Comment: Hi, anjo! In addition to the tips that T.J. Crowder mentioned, it's also good manners to _not_ erase your question, for the benefit of other readers :) Also, if someones answer helped, you, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted!

Answer (score 2):

You could append the timestamp of the time of deletion to the filename in your Trash folder.  Upon restore, you could strip this off again.

Answer (score 2):

To add a timestamp to your file, use something like this:

```
DT=$(date +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
mv $PWD/"$1" "/$HOME/Trash/${1}.${DT}"
```

This will, e.g., create a file like `initrd.img-2.6.28-11-generic.20110615-140159` when moving `initrd.img-2.6.28-11-generic`.

To get the original filename, strip everything starting from the last dot, like with:

```
NAME_WITHOUT_TIMESTAMP=${file%.*-*}
```

The pattern is on the right side after the percentage char. (`.*` would also be enough to match.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look how trash-cli does it. It's written in Python and uses the same trash bin as desktop environments. Trash-cli is available at least in the big Linux distributions.

http://code.google.com/p/trash-cli/

Answer (score -1):

Probably the easiest thing to do is simply add -i to the invocation of mv.  That will prompt the user whether or not to replace.  If you happen to have access to gnu cp (eg, on Linux), you could use cp --backup instead of mv.

Comment: Hmm, this means that the user can't delete two files of same name (and restore them both)?

Comment: @Paulo That is correct.  If the OP wants to implement a versioning file system, he would be better off installing a versioning file system.  Re-inventing the wheel is never a good idea.